# Does JSch support seek() on uploads

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

Does the JSch library support inserting/seeking() chunks of data into a file?

Currently I have a Spring Batch ItemWriter that writes data chunks of a file to my remote SFTP server. The data chunks I receive are in order and each data chunk contains the starting position respective to the file. Currently I have not tried to use parallelism for uploading data chunks to my SFTP server as I have not found any method to write data chunks out of order. To do this unordered upload I need to be able to seek().

Is this feature possible using JSch or is this a limitation of the SFTP protocol itself? If this is a limitation of the JSch library, is there another library that would support this feature?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: The protocol supports it at the packet level, but Jsch [apparently supports it only at the operation (put) level](https://github.com/is/jsch/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.java#L723) which means more packets and roundtrips, which may or may not be a problem for you. (Also I suspect modes other than 'OVERWRITE' probably won't work right, but not verified.)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I have attempted to do what you have suggested but Jsch seems to still misplace data chunks despite me providing the exact offsets. I have converted to using SSHJ. I posted a question about using [SSHJ and file chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69023031/why-is-the-sshj-maximum-write-size-32kb). If you could please take a look at it I would greatly appreciate it.